# Is there a MicroPython console equivalent to any()?

Tags: input, console, buffer, micropython

Is there any way to look for console input under MicroPython without pausing the program?

Within a program, I can use, for example, **uart1.any()** to see if there is anything in the input buffer.  If not, the program can just continue.

I have a system that runs autonomously.  However, I want to be able to modify parameters after the program has started using the console.  The problem is, if I just use **input()** then the program will pause, even if I don't want to take any action.

What I need is to be able to check the "console input buffer" periodically to see if I have entered anything and, if so, process that input, otherwise to just continue.

Is this possible?

=====================================

Many thanks for the suggestion!  It works, but...

What I am trying to do is to run a process which can be interrupted by keyboard input and diverted to another process.  When that is finished, I return to the original process.

The initial part works well; I poll stdin and nothing happens until I hit return (for example).  The program then correctly diverts to the other routine.  However, when that is finished, and I return to the original thread, it immediately diverts again, even though I have not pressed any further keys.

I have tried setting 'keypress' to None after trapping it; I have tried using stdin.flush - which doesn't work!  It's as though there is still something in the input buffer that I need to purge.

Any ideas?

Comment: From the (now archived) micropython forum:  https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=12162&p=66276&hilit=non+blocking#p66276

Answer (score 0):

You can poll stdin to see if data is available before attempting to read it.

```
from sys import stdin
from select import poll, POLLIN

poll_obj = poll()
poll_obj.register(stdin, POLLIN)
keypress = stdin.read(1) if poll_obj.poll(0) else None
print(keypress)
```